# How do I delete a file using it's path on Android 7?

Tags: java, android, file

I have a file on a memory card with path: `/storage/7AB3-1EEF/EXTERNAL_eicar-tf.com`

With the `File` class, I can read it, but I can't delete it.

So, how do I delete the file using only the real path to it? 
My code works if file stored in `/storage/0/[file]`

Permissions written in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The code fully works on Android 4.2.2

I tried converting the file to a URI and deleting it, but I've got an "unknown URL" error message.

```
Uri ur = Uri.fromFile(new File(reports.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath()));
context.getContentResolver().delete(ur, null, null);
```

My button's code:

```
button_Delete_File.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) { 
                    File file = new File(reports.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath()); //Here comes out the described path...
                    file.delete();
                    Log.e("File deleted?", reports.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath());
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        Log.e("Yes", reports.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath());
                    } else {
                        Log.e("No", reports.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath());
                        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_file_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: "how-to delete file having only real path to it?" -- you don't. You do not have read-write access to arbitrary files on removable storage. Eventually, you will not have read-write access to arbitrary files on *any* form of storage.

Comment: Then how comes that it works on internal storage?

Comment: `/storage/0/[file]` is external storage, from the standpoint of the Android SDK.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for that misspoint. But it fully works there!..
So, why I can't just do the same on memory card?
I mean they both clarified as "external"...

Comment: Google is slowly increasing the restrictions on where apps can read and write, for privacy and security reasons. Android Q and R will block you from working with existing files on most of external storage as well. Google is steering developers towards things like the Storage Access Framework, for user-mediated storage access.

Comment: Then can I ask you to provide sample of choosing and deleting files using SAF?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a sample that deletes content.

Comment: Anyway thank you very much! Thanks to your tip about SAF I reworked my code so now it works on Android 4.2.2 and 7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it! Thanks for [Mr. CommonsWare's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869472/android-7-how-to-delete-file-having-its-path#comment98400338_55869472) point about Storage Access Framework I was able to rework my code:

```
button_Delete_File.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) { //Remove item from list and delete assigned file.
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
           try {
               Uri uri = Uri.parse(reports.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath());
               ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
               contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
               DocumentsContract.deleteDocument(contentResolver, uri);
               reports.remove(getAdapterPosition());
               notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_file_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       } else {
           File file = new File(reports.get(getAdapterPosition()).getPath());
           file.delete();
           if (!file.exists()) {
               reports.remove(getAdapterPosition());
               notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.delete_file_error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   }
});
```

Now it works on Android 4.2.2 and 7.0.